# Cannot see Swift classes from test target

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, xcode6

I have an iOS app using both ObjC and Swift code. I tried setting up a test target for it today with no success. I have a single test case class written in Swift. I imported my app's module there. I made sure the classes I am trying to access are public. But I cannot see them from my test target. I can see ObjC code from there though.
I tried the exact same steps on a dummy project and there it worked fine.
I don't want to add the classes for testing to the test target's compile sources. I am also using Xcode 6.3 and updating to Xcode 7 is not an option for me at the moment.
Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue went away after deleting and recreating the test target.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure your import is marked with a @testable annotation. For example, you want:

```
@testable import myprojectname
```

as opposed to:

```
import myprojectname
```

Comment: The @testable annotation comes with Swift 2 and at the moment I cannot update to Xcode 7.

Comment: This only applies to Swift tests; if the tests are in ObjC you can't do `@testable import`